# Can't detect error in this query

Tags: mysql, sql

Is this query well done? I tried it but it failed somehow... The ids are referred as unique so the correlation between the tables should work but it doesn't...

> $query = "SELECT
>   table1.id,table1.field1,table1.field2,table1.field3 FROM
>   table1,table2 WHERE table1.id='(CASE WHEN '5' =
>   table2.id1 THEN table2.id2 WHEN '5' =
>   table2.id2 THEN table2.id1)' WHERE
>   table2.field6='done'";

ERROR:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' = relationships.id1 THEN relationships.id2 WHEN '1' = relationships.id2 THEN ' at line 1

Comment: Are you getting an error or just unexpected results? Please be more descriptive in your question.

Comment: error in 2 where clause? use and for multiple conditions

Comment: In addition to the two WHERE clauses that another commenter mentioned, you have quotes around your CASE expression, which is wrong.

Comment: I don't see any join between table1 and table2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gordon is right. Maybe this is closer to a working statement:

```
SELECT table1.id,table1.field1,table1.field2,table1.field3
FROM table1,table2
WHERE table1.id= (CASE WHEN '5' = table2.id1 THEN table2.id2 WHEN '5' = table2.id2 THEN table2.id1)
AND table2.field6='done';
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your query, formatted for a human being:

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.field1, table1.field2, table1.field3
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.id='(CASE WHEN '5' = table2.id1 THEN table2.id2 WHEN '5' = table2.id2 THEN table2.id1)'
WHERE table2.field6='done'
```

This query is broken in so many ways, that I don't know where to start.  But, you can start by understanding that `case` statements shouldn't be surrounded by single quotes.  And that SQL queries don't have two `where` clauses.  And you should learn proper `join` syntax.

This might be what you want:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.field1, t1.field2, t1.field3
FROM table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = 5 and 5 in (t2.id1, t2.id2)
WHERE table2.field6 = 'done'
```